# Question about returning a boolean from a reducer function

Tags: javascript, reduce, boolean-expression

I'm trying to figure out why, in my reducer function, can isTrue flip to `true` from `false`, but not back to `false` when encountering a function that returns false .  I'm just trying to understand why it can flip one way but not the other.

I know the flip happens in `return isTrue || val(num);`

Directions were "// define a function "passOne" which takes two arguments, the first is any value and the second is an array of functions. These functions can be considered tests, as they will all return either true or false. "passOne" will iterate/loop through the array and pass the value to each function as an argument. If at least one function(test) returns true, "passOne" will return true. If none of the functions return true, "passOne" will return false. // use your "passOne" to determine if the number 113 is negative, even, OR has 1 as the first digit. Then test 213."

i've tried visualizing it in Python Tutor.

```js
function isNeg(num){
  return num < 0 ? true: false;
}

function isEven(num){
  return num % 2 === 0 ? true : false;
}

function oneDig(num){
  return (num.toString())[0] === `1` ? true : false;
}

const funcs = [oneDig, isNeg, isEven];

// refactor "passOne" so that it uses the built-in "reduce" method instead of a "for" loop

function passOne(num, arr){
  return arr.reduce((isTrue, val) => {
    return isTrue || val(num);
  }, false);
}

console.log(passOne(113, funcs)); //true
console.log(passOne(213, funcs)); //false
```

code is behaving as expected, I'm just not understanding why callbacks that return 'false' don't flip isTrue back to 'false', how does it stay 'true' and then not update to 'false', not that that's what the instructions say to do, i'm just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 113,

accumulator is `false` initialized.
So first time **isTrue will be false**. So it executes `val(num)`.

**Logical OR will go to next condition if its false, otherwise it wont go.**

oneDig is the first item in the arr. oneDig checks for first digit of that number is 1.

so for 113, first digit is 1. So it returns true. After for other two val(num) is not executed since isTrue = true satisfies the LogicalOR.

For 213,

oneDig returns false. So it goes to val(num)

isNeg returns also false. So it goes again to val(num)

finally isEven also returns false.

So its like its like `Array.prototype.some` to check any function in arr returns true, then finally it returns true else check for all functions and if nothing returns true, it will return false

Answer (score 1):

It can never become `false` again when `isTrue` becomes `true`.

Because you are using `||` operator. Consider `isTrue` is `true`. Then it doesn't matter what callback returns the whole value will will `true`.

```js
console.log(true || false)
```

You actually don't need `reduce()` here because one of the condition is true you don't need to check further.You should use `some()` in this case.

```
const passOne = (num, arr) => arr.some(x => x(num))
```

If you want to flip then it means you want the code to check for all the conditions. Then you need to use `&&` operator. And pass `true` instead of `false` to `reduce()`

```js
function isNeg(num){
  return num < 0 ? true: false;
}

function isEven(num){
  return num % 2 === 0 ? true : false;
}

function oneDig(num){
  return (num.toString())[1] === `1` ? true : false;
}

const funcs = [oneDig, isNeg, isEven];

// refactor "passOne" so that it uses the built-in "reduce" method instead of a "for" loop

function passAll(num, arr){
  return arr.reduce((isTrue, val) => {
    return isTrue && val(num);
  }, true);
}

console.log(passAll(113, funcs)); //false
console.log(passAll(213, funcs)); //false
console.log(passAll(-122, funcs)) //true
```

Or another way to do that is `every()`

```
const passOne = (num, arr) => arr.every(x => x(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and return the result of the callback.

```js
const
    isNeg = num => num < 0,
    isEven = num => num % 2 === 0,
    oneDig = num => num.toString()[0] === '1',
    funcs = [oneDig, isNeg, isEven],
    passOne = (num, arr) => arr.some(fn => fn(num));

console.log(passOne(113, funcs)); //true
console.log(passOne(213, funcs)); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `some` which tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```
const isNeg = num => num < 0;
const isEven = num => num % 2 === 0;
const oneDig = num => (num.toString())[0] === `1`;
const passOne = (num, arr) => arr.some(fn => fn(num));

const funcs = [oneDig, isNeg, isEven];

console.log(passOne(113, funcs)); //true
console.log(passOne(213, funcs)); //false
```